# jupyter notebook jumps after evaluation of cell

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

In my Jupyter notebook, every time I evaluate a cell at the bottom of the page, the notebook jumps up so that it hides part of the output.

Here is an example with pictures. In this picture I want to evaluate the last cell.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgIuR.jpg

After evaluation, the screen jumps up so I can't see the last part of the output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfbKB.jpg

So every time I have to scroll up manually to get back the view. Is there a setting here I can tweak to eliminate this issue?

Here's information from the "about" page of Jupyter:

> The version of the notebook server is 3.2.1-2d95975 and is running on:
>   Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.2 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  1 2013,
>   12:41:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> Current Kernel Information:
>
> Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.2 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  1 2013,
>   12:41:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] Type "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.
>
> IPython 3.2.1

Answer (score 11):

You may add few cells below your last `code cell` to avoid this issue.!!!

When you press `ctrl+enter` to run the last cell (infact any cell), the DOM of notebook removes the existing output. So the browser clears some content below it and scrolls up. But python output is displayed only after few microseconds, so the output is only partly visible. Unaware of any other method to overcome this issue.

Comment: I'm using `print("\n" * 100)` in the bottom cell.

Comment: Nice workaround. This is a really annoying UX issue.

Comment: @bluenote10 It should be an answer :D